# Why this is true: parseInt(1111111111111111,2) === parseInt(11111111111111111,2)

Tags: javascript

This question is simply to curiosity.

Via console

```
parseInt(1111111111111111,2) // 16 1's
```

returns

```
65535
```

and

```
parseInt(11111111111111111,2) // 17 1's
```

returns

```
65535
```

Also

```
//          16 1's                           17 1's
if(parseInt(1111111111111111,2) === parseInt(11111111111111111,2))
```

returns

```
true
```

Where is the trick?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Try just `11111111111111111`.

Comment: The first argument for `parseInt` **must be** a string. It's GIGO.

Comment: `(1111111111111111).toString() === "1111111111111111"` and `(11111111111111111).toString() === "11111111111111112"`. `parseInt` expects a string, and `2` is an invalid binary digit.

Comment: @zerkms—the first thing that [*parseInt*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) does is call *ToString* on the first argument, so no, it does not need to be a string.

Comment: @RobG it does indeed, when data is already broken. The interface **requires** it to be a string, no matter what it does internally.

Comment: @zerkms—the result isn't because a number is passed to *parseInt* as your comment suggests, but because of IEEE 754 arithmetic.

Comment: @RobG I know why it happened. And I still stand on my point: if one followed the interface requirements - there wouldn't be a problem. When you pass garbage - you get garbage as a result.

Comment: @RobG It needs to be a string if you want it to process the argument as it appears literally in the code.

Comment: @zerkms—I was just pointing out that the statement "*The first argument for parseInt **must** be a string*" is not consistent with the standard. It's not *required* to be a string and is often applied to Number types to truncate the decimal part (which I know you're aware of, but these threads aren't just for you and me).

Comment: @RobG it must be a string for the result to be meaningful and consistent. Interface states the first element is a `string`. Standard states the first element is a string. `parseInt (string , radix)` <--- here. JS does not support type hinting, if it did the signature would be `parseInt(String string, Unsigned radix)` "and is often applied to Number types to truncate the decimal part" --- just because people mis-use instruments does not mean it valid.

Comment: @zerkms—I wouldn't call it abuse, the spec doesn't say if the argument isn't a string to throw an error. As Lucas Trzesniewski pointed out, `11111111111111111` is first converted to the Number `11111111111111112`, which becomes the String '`11111111111111112'` and since '2' isn't a valid number in base 2 it's stripped by *parseInt* so the result is that the OP is comparing two strings of 16 ones. SLaks hints at this but doesn't state it explicitly.

Comment: @RobG for me "produces an integer value dictated by interpretation of the contents of the *string* argument" sounds like the first argument must be a string. "Leading white space in string is ignored" --- what other type in JS may have leading spaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`11111111111111111` is a decimal number literal for a number that is too large for Javascript to encode precisely.

`parseInt(, 2)` will stop at the first character that isn't `1` or `0`, so it stops parsing once the precision degrades.

Change that to a string and you'll be fine.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought JavaScript uses 64 bit integers?

Comment: @self: No; it uses 64-bit _floats_.  There is an important difference.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 java !================= javascript

Comment: @SLaks 64bit *doubles* ;-)

Comment: @SLaks I I know the difference between a float and an integer. I was just clarifying

Comment: @zerkms or a [*double-precision floating-point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) number :-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski that's what I was in doubt actually :-) If you can call a double precision number a "float" in any extra-pedantically valid context :-)